# Node JS Unhandler Error Event

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

I am a newbie here, i am trying to write a code, which used node's event emitter in it, see the below code,

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var errors = require('./errors');

var defaults ={
    default_api_endpoint_v0 : "someapi",
    oauth_c_key: "oauth_consumer_key",
    options_check: ['oauth_consumer_key']
};

var someapi = function(options){
    this.options = options;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
    if(!this.options)
        this.emit('error',errors.options_not_passed);
        return;
        //return errors.options_not_passed
    if(!this.checkOptions()){
        return errors.options_passed_not_satisfied
    }

};

someapi.prototype = Object.create(EventEmitter.prototype);

someapi.prototype.checkOptions = function(){
    var thatOptions = this.options;
    var bool = false;
    if(typeof thatOptions !== 'object')
      return errors.options_passed_not_satisfied;
    Object.keys(thatOptions).forEach(function(key){
        Object.keys(defaults.options_check).forEach(function(Key){
            if(key === defaults.options_check[Key]){
                bool = true;
            }
        })
    });
    return bool;
};

module.exports = someapi
```

and i am invoking it like this below,

```
var op = new someapi();

op.on('error',function(err){
    console.log("Emitted" + err);
})
```

But it throws this error, i dunno what i a doing wrong,

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Please pass the options                                      
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\gitHub\someapi\lib\errors.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\gitHub\someapi\lib\api.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

In tha above error, **Please pass the options is returned by me**, it is located in the errors file, see below,

```
module.exports = {
    options_not_passed : new Error("Please pass the options"),
    options_passed_not_satisfied : "Please check are you sending all the options_params"
};
```

Could some one, provide me some inputs what i am doing here wrong???

And to the above, i know i am not passing options object while creating object to the someapi class. i want to know why my error is not getting handled in the "on" event.

P.S Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're emitting the error *from the constructor*. There is no way to be able to attach a listener (or do anything else with the object) *while* the instance is being created (because you don't have a reference to the new object that is returned from `new someapi()` yet).

Comment: hi mscdex, thanks for the input, i solved it by invoking from constructor itself, like the below,  setTimeout(function({self.emit('error',errors.options_not_passed);},0); is that good practice?

Comment: Not really. A common way of dealing with these kinds of immediate errors is to throw an error instance (e.g. `throw errors.options_not_passed`). Just make sure whatever you throw is an actual Error instance and not just a string.